# javascript: create dictionary array from array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of strings.

```
const periods = ["2021-03-31", "2021-02-28", "2021-01-31"]
```

I want to create a dictionary array from this array. My result should look like this:

```
[
   {value: "2021-03-31",label : "2021-03-31"}, 
   {value: "2021-02-28",label : "2021-02-28"}, 
   {value: "2021-01-31",label : "2021-01-31"}
]
```

Is it possible to do it with map function.

```
const periodsDictArray = periods.map(el => ??? )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return an object from `array#map` callback.

```js
const periods = ["2021-03-31", "2021-02-28", "2021-01-31"],
      result = periods.map(value => ({value, label: value}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```